# Show paused SKScene under another semitransparent SKScene

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I'm currently pausing an SKScene containing gameplay, and presenting another SKScene containing a menu above it, using `self.view?.presentScene()`.

The menu scene has a transparent background, and during the transition, I can properly see the paused game underneath. But when the transition completes, the background abruptly turns black, which suggests to me that the gameplay scene has disappeared.

Is there a way to preserve the paused game while I display the menu?

Answer (score 1):

`SKView` can present only one scene at a time.

However, you can still architect your game to encapsulate a menu as its own "scene" — it just can't be an `SKScene`. Make the menu a node, and add it to the game scene. (If you need to do things like setting `paused` on the game scene when you show your menu, put all the game content into a subnode of the game scene, and pause that.) You can even repeat this process for submenus. And you can use the Xcode scene editor to make your menus — just make sure that the menu content in each `.sks` file is in a subnode you can pull out and re-parent into your live scene when you load the file.

You can see an example of this in Apple's [Bananas](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Bananas/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014450) sample code project. That's a SceneKit (3D) game, but it uses a SpriteKit scene for its HUD and menus, using this technique to swap different menu content in and out.

Answer (score 0):

There is another way.

The menu should be a parent node with children nodes added to it.  It should not be its own scene.

When you want to display your menu, pause the game and add the menu parent node to the scene.

Comment: I did this originally, but since the scene containing the menu node is paused, I'm prevented from doing any animations in the menu. I'm hoping for a solution that lets me pause the game but update the menu.

Comment: You could add all of your "gameplay" nodes to a master "game node" and all of your menu items to the scene itself.  When you want to pause the game then pause the "master game node" rather than the scene itself.

Comment: This works perfectly. I didn't know nodes themselves had a `paused` property. Is there any reason to be wary of this technique, or is it just as safe as pausing a scene?

Comment: Should be safe.  You can pause individual nodes as well.